# Reading and plotting HDF5(.h5) file and showing map for a specific latitude and longitude

Tags: python, numpy, mapping, hdf5

I got a HDF5 file from MOSDAC website named 3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5 and I'm tying to read the this file and visualize the TIR and VIS dataset in the file in map. Since I am new to programming I don't have much idea how to do this for a specific location on the global data using the Latitude and longitude values. My problem statement is to show data for Indian region.

The coding I have done till now:

```
#Importing libraries`

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
import os
import netCDF4 as nc
import seaborn as sns
import geopandas as gpd  

#Reading and listing keys present in HDF

fn = '3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5' #filename (the ".h5" file)
f = h5py.File(fn)
list(f.keys())

#extract data from the HDF5 file
mir = f['IMG_MIR'][:]  #middle infra-red
swir = f['IMG_SWIR'][:] #shortwave IR
tir1 = f['IMG_TIR1'][:] #Thermal IR1
tir2 = f['IMG_TIR2'][:] #Thermal IR2
vis = f['IMG_VIS'][:]   #Visible count
wv = f['IMG_WV'][:]     #Water vapor count
lat = f['Latitude'][:] 
lon = f['Longitude'][:]
lat_vis = f['Latitude_VIS'][:]
lon_vis = f['Longitude_VIS'][:]
lat_wv = f['Latitude_WV'][:]
lon_wv = f['Longitude_WV'][:]

vis = f['IMG_MIR'][0,:,:]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
im1 = plt.imshow(vis)
plt.colorbar(im1)

tir1d = f['/IMG_TIR1'];
lat = f['/Latitude'];
lon = f['/Longitude'];
   
Lat = np.linspace(81.041527, -81.041527, 2805)
Lon = np.linspace(0.84329641, 163.15671, 2816)

shp = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\offic\shape\IND_adm0.shp')

%lat=0:gs:60;%INDIA
%lon=60:gs:100;
```

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data = Dataset(r'C:\Users\offic\3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5')
data

Out: <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF4 data model, file format HDF5):
    conventions: CF-1.6
    title: 3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B
    institute: BES,SAC/ISRO,Ahmedabad,INDIA.
    source: BES,SAC/ISRO,Ahmedabad,INDIA.
    Unique_Id: 3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000
    Satellite_Name: INSAT-3D
    Sensor_Id: IMG
    Sensor_Name: IMAGER
    HDF_Product_File_Name: 3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5
    Output_Format: hdf5-1.8.8
    Station_Id: BES
    Ground_Station: BES,SAC/ISRO,Ahmedabad,INDIA.
    Product_Type: STANDARD(FULL DISK)
    Processing_Level: L1B
    Imaging_Mode: FULL FRAME
    Acquisition_Date: 30MAR2018
    Acquisition_Time_in_GMT: 0000
    Acquisition_Start_Time: 30-MAR-2018T00:00:08
    Acquisition_End_Time: 30-MAR-2018T00:26:58
    Product_Creation_Time: 2018-03-30T06:03:39
    Radiometric_Calibration_Type: LAB CALIBRATED
    Nominal_Altitude(km): 36000.0
    Observed_Altitude(km): 35787.8215
    Field_of_View(degrees): 17.973925
    Nominal_Central_Point_Coordinates(degrees)_Latitude_Longitude: [ 0. 82.]
    Attitude_Source: STAR
    Sun_Azimuth(Degrees): 86.314133
    Sat_Azimuth(Degrees): 286.793152
    Sat_Elevation(Degrees): 89.813721
    Sun_Elevation(Degrees): -6.010917
    FastScan_Linearity_Enabled: no
    SlowScan_Linearity_Enabled: no
    MCD_FS_Enabled: no
    MCD_SS_Enabled: no
    Yaw_Flip_Flag: Y
    Software_Version: 1.0
    TIR1_Gain_Mode: 2
    TIR2_Gain_Mode: 2
    MIR_Gain_Mode: 2
    WV_Gain_Mode: 3
    VIS_Gain_Mode: 2
    SWIR_Gain_Mode: 3
    TIR1_Acquisition_Mode: MAIN
    TIR2_Acquisition_Mode: MAIN
    MIR_Acquisition_Mode: MAIN
    WV_Acquisition_Mode: MAIN
    VIS_Acquisition_Mode: MAIN
    SWIR_Acquisition_Mode: MAIN
    left_longitude: 0.8432964
    right_longitude: 163.15671
    upper_latitude: 81.04153
    lower_latitude: -81.04153
    Datum: WGS84
    Ellipsoid: WGS84
    dimensions(sizes): GeoX(2805), GeoX1(1402), GeoX2(11220), GeoY(2816), GeoY1(1408), GeoY2(11264), GreyCount(1024), time(1)
    variables(dimensions): int32 GeoX(GeoX), int32 GeoX1(GeoX1), int32 GeoX2(GeoX2), int32 GeoY(GeoY), int32 GeoY1(GeoY1), int32 GeoY2(GeoY2), int32 GreyCount(GreyCount), uint16 IMG_MIR(time, GeoY, GeoX), float32 IMG_MIR_RADIANCE(GreyCount), float32 IMG_MIR_TEMP(GreyCount), uint16 IMG_SWIR(time, GeoY2, GeoX2), float32 IMG_SWIR_RADIANCE(GreyCount), uint16 IMG_TIR1(time, GeoY, GeoX), float32 IMG_TIR1_RADIANCE(GreyCount), float32 IMG_TIR1_TEMP(GreyCount), uint16 IMG_TIR2(time, GeoY, GeoX), float32 IMG_TIR2_RADIANCE(GreyCount), float32 IMG_TIR2_TEMP(GreyCount), uint16 IMG_VIS(time, GeoY2, GeoX2), float32 IMG_VIS_ALBEDO(GreyCount), float32 IMG_VIS_RADIANCE(GreyCount), uint16 IMG_WV(time, GeoY1, GeoX1), float32 IMG_WV_RADIANCE(GreyCount), float32 IMG_WV_TEMP(GreyCount), int16 Latitude(GeoY, GeoX), int32 Latitude_VIS(GeoY2, GeoX2), int16 Latitude_WV(GeoY1, GeoX1), int16 Longitude(GeoY, GeoX), int32 Longitude_VIS(GeoY2, GeoX2), int16 Longitude_WV(GeoY1, GeoX1), <class 'str'> SCAN_LINE_TIME(GeoY1), uint16 Sat_Azimuth(time, GeoY, GeoX), int16 Sat_Elevation(time, GeoY, GeoX), uint16 Sun_Azimuth(time, GeoY, GeoX), int16 Sun_Elevation(time, GeoY, GeoX), float64 time(time)
    groups: 

data.variables
Out: {'GeoX': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 GeoX(GeoX)
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (2805,)
 filling off,
 'GeoX1': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 GeoX1(GeoX1)
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1402,)
 filling off,
 'GeoX2': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 GeoX2(GeoX2)
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (11220,)
 filling off,
 'GeoY': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 GeoY(GeoY)
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (2816,)
 filling off,
 'GeoY1': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 GeoY1(GeoY1)
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1408,)
 filling off,
 'GeoY2': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 GeoY2(GeoY2)
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (11264,)
 filling off,
 'GreyCount': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 GreyCount(GreyCount)
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling off,
 'IMG_MIR': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 IMG_MIR(time, GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: Middle Infrared Count
     invert: true
     central_wavelength: 3.9313
     bandwidth: 0.2
     wavelength_unit: micron
     bits_per_pixel: 10
     resolution: 4.0
     resolution_unit: km
     _FillValue: 1023
     lab_radiance_scale_factor: 0.000283937
     lab_radiance_add_offset: -0.00401529
     lab_radiance_quad: 0.0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor_gsics: 0.000366208
     lab_radiance_add_offset_gsics: -0.00833466
     lab_radiance_quad_gsics: 0.0
     radiance_units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     coordinates: time Latitude Longitude
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'IMG_MIR_RADIANCE': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_MIR_RADIANCE(GreyCount)
     long_name: Middle Infrared Radiance
     invert: true
     units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_MIR_TEMP': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_MIR_TEMP(GreyCount)
     long_name: Middle Infrared Brightness Temperature
     invert: true
     units: K
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_SWIR': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 IMG_SWIR(time, GeoY2, GeoX2)
     long_name: Shortwave Infrared Count
     invert: false
     central_wavelength: 1.625
     bandwidth: 0.15
     wavelength_unit: micron
     bits_per_pixel: 10
     resolution: 1.0
     resolution_unit: km
     _FillValue: 0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor: 0.007835
     lab_radiance_add_offset: -0.172166
     lab_radiance_quad: 0.0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor_gsics: 0.007835
     lab_radiance_add_offset_gsics: -0.172166
     lab_radiance_quad_gsics: 0.0
     radiance_units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     coordinates: time Latitude_VIS Longitude_VIS
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 11264, 11220)
 filling on,
 'IMG_SWIR_RADIANCE': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_SWIR_RADIANCE(GreyCount)
     long_name: Shortwave Infrared Radiance
     invert: false
     units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_TIR1': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 IMG_TIR1(time, GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: Thermal Infrared1 Count
     invert: true
     central_wavelength: 10.8288
     bandwidth: 1.0
     wavelength_unit: micron
     bits_per_pixel: 10
     resolution: 4.0
     resolution_unit: km
     _FillValue: 1023
     lab_radiance_scale_factor: 0.00163731
     lab_radiance_add_offset: -0.0199179
     lab_radiance_quad: 0.0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor_gsics: 0.00203982
     lab_radiance_add_offset_gsics: -0.118067
     lab_radiance_quad_gsics: 0.0
     radiance_units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     coordinates: time Latitude Longitude
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'IMG_TIR1_RADIANCE': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_TIR1_RADIANCE(GreyCount)
     long_name: Thermal Infrared1 Radiance
     invert: true
     units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_TIR1_TEMP': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_TIR1_TEMP(GreyCount)
     units: K
     _FillValue: 999.0
     long_name: Thermal Infrared1 Brightness Temperature
     invert: true
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_TIR2': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 IMG_TIR2(time, GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: Thermal Infrared2 Count
     invert: true
     central_wavelength: 11.9593
     bandwidth: 1.0
     wavelength_unit: micron
     bits_per_pixel: 10
     resolution: 4.0
     resolution_unit: km
     _FillValue: 1023
     lab_radiance_scale_factor: 0.00143966
     lab_radiance_add_offset: -0.017032
     lab_radiance_quad: 0.0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor_gsics: 0.00181987
     lab_radiance_add_offset_gsics: -0.090434
     lab_radiance_quad_gsics: 0.0
     radiance_units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     coordinates: time Latitude Longitude
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'IMG_TIR2_RADIANCE': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_TIR2_RADIANCE(GreyCount)
     _FillValue: 999.0
     long_name: Thermal Infrared2 Radiance
     invert: true
     units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_TIR2_TEMP': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_TIR2_TEMP(GreyCount)
     long_name: Thermal Infrared2 Brightness Temperature
     invert: true
     units: K
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_VIS': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 IMG_VIS(time, GeoY2, GeoX2)
     long_name: Visible Count
     invert: false
     central_wavelength: 0.65
     bandwidth: 0.25
     wavelength_unit: micron
     bits_per_pixel: 10
     resolution: 1.0
     resolution_unit: km
     _FillValue: 0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor: 0.0630857
     lab_radiance_add_offset: -1.85891
     lab_radiance_quad: 0.0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor_gsics: 0.0630857
     lab_radiance_add_offset_gsics: -1.85891
     lab_radiance_quad_gsics: 0.0
     radiance_units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     coordinates: time Latitude_VIS Longitude_VIS
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 11264, 11220)
 filling on,
 'IMG_VIS_ALBEDO': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_VIS_ALBEDO(GreyCount)
     long_name: Visible Albedo
     invert: false
     units: %
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,
 'IMG_VIS_RADIANCE': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_VIS_RADIANCE(GreyCount)
     long_name: Visible Radiance
     invert: false
     units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_WV': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 IMG_WV(time, GeoY1, GeoX1)
     long_name: Water Vapor Count
     invert: true
     central_wavelength: 6.8841
     bandwidth: 0.6
     wavelength_unit: micron
     bits_per_pixel: 10
     resolution: 8.0
     resolution_unit: km
     _FillValue: 1023
     lab_radiance_scale_factor: 0.000858417
     lab_radiance_add_offset: 0.000380381
     lab_radiance_quad: 0.0
     lab_radiance_scale_factor_gsics: 0.00125055
     lab_radiance_add_offset_gsics: -0.0299274
     lab_radiance_quad_gsics: 0.0
     radiance_units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     coordinates: time Latitude_WV Longitude_WV
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 1408, 1402)
 filling on,
 'IMG_WV_RADIANCE': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_WV_RADIANCE(GreyCount)
     long_name: Water Vapor Radiance
     invert: true
     units: mW.cm-2.sr-1.micron-1
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'IMG_WV_TEMP': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 IMG_WV_TEMP(GreyCount)
     long_name: Water Vapor Brightness Temperature
     invert: true
     units: K
     _FillValue: 999.0
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1024,)
 filling on,
 'Latitude': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int16 Latitude(GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: latitude
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.01
     units: degrees_north
     _FillValue: 32767
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'Latitude_VIS': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 Latitude_VIS(GeoY2, GeoX2)
     long_name: latitude
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.001
     units: degrees_north
     _FillValue: 327670
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (11264, 11220)
 filling on,
 'Latitude_WV': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int16 Latitude_WV(GeoY1, GeoX1)
     long_name: latitude
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.01
     units: degrees_north
     _FillValue: 32767
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1408, 1402)
 filling on,
 'Longitude': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int16 Longitude(GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: longitude
     units: degrees_east
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.01
     _FillValue: 32767
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'Longitude_VIS': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int32 Longitude_VIS(GeoY2, GeoX2)
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.001
     long_name: longitude
     units: degrees_east
     _FillValue: 327670
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (11264, 11220)
 filling on,
 'Longitude_WV': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int16 Longitude_WV(GeoY1, GeoX1)
     long_name: longitude
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.01
     units: degrees_east
     _FillValue: 32767
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1408, 1402)
 filling on,
 'SCAN_LINE_TIME': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 vlen SCAN_LINE_TIME(GeoY1)
     long_name: Scan Time for Water Vapor Resolution
 vlen data type: <class 'str'>
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1408,),
 'Sat_Azimuth': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 Sat_Azimuth(time, GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: Satellite Azimuth
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.01
     units: degree
     _FillValue: 65535
     coordinates: time Latitude Longitude
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'Sat_Elevation': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int16 Sat_Elevation(time, GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: Satellite Elevation
     add_offset: 0.0
     units: degree
     scale_factor: 0.01
     _FillValue: 32767
     coordinates: time Latitude Longitude
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'Sun_Azimuth': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 uint16 Sun_Azimuth(time, GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: Sun Azimuth
     add_offset: 0.0
     units: degree
     scale_factor: 0.01
     _FillValue: 65535
     coordinates: time Latitude Longitude
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'Sun_Elevation': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 int16 Sun_Elevation(time, GeoY, GeoX)
     long_name: Sun Elevation
     add_offset: 0.0
     scale_factor: 0.01
     units: degree
     _FillValue: 32767
     coordinates: time Latitude Longitude
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1, 2816, 2805)
 filling on,
 'time': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float64 time(time)
     units: minutes since 2000-01-01 00:00:00
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (1,)
 filling off}

data.variables.keys()
Out: dict_keys(['GeoX', 'GeoX1', 'GeoX2', 'GeoY', 'GeoY1', 'GeoY2', 'GreyCount', 'IMG_MIR', 'IMG_MIR_RADIANCE', 'IMG_MIR_TEMP', 'IMG_SWIR', 'IMG_SWIR_RADIANCE', 'IMG_TIR1', 'IMG_TIR1_RADIANCE', 'IMG_TIR1_TEMP', 'IMG_TIR2', 'IMG_TIR2_RADIANCE', 'IMG_TIR2_TEMP', 'IMG_VIS', 'IMG_VIS_ALBEDO', 'IMG_VIS_RADIANCE', 'IMG_WV', 'IMG_WV_RADIANCE', 'IMG_WV_TEMP', 'Latitude', 'Latitude_VIS', 'Latitude_WV', 'Longitude', 'Longitude_VIS', 'Longitude_WV', 'SCAN_LINE_TIME', 'Sat_Azimuth', 'Sat_Elevation', 'Sun_Azimuth', 'Sun_Elevation', 'time'])

lats = data.variables['Latitude'][:]
lons = data.variables['Longitude'][:]
tir = data.variables['IMG_TIR1'][:]

lats.shape
Out:(2816, 2805)
lons.shape
Out:(2816, 2805)
tir.shape
Out:(1, 2816, 2805)

` I was not so sure about exact lat and lon that I want to plot so here's two of them. Although I think the 1st one is the correct one`

#mp = Basemap(projection = 'merc', 
            # llcrnrlon  = 68.766521,
            # llcrnrlat  = 3.323179,
            # urcrnrlon  = 100.202163, 
            # urcrnrlat  = 37.315495,
            # resolution = 'i')

mp = Basemap(projection = 'merc', 
             llcrnrlon  = 0.8432964,
             llcrnrlat  = -81.04153,
             urcrnrlon  = 163.15671, 
             urcrnrlat  = 81.04153,
             resolution = 'i')

` I'm getting an error in this line dk what it is`

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
Out: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12060/1726626783.py in <module>
----> 1 lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in meshgrid(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in meshgrid(copy, sparse, indexing, *xi)
   4947 
   4948     if copy:
-> 4949         output = [x.copy() for x in output]
   4950 
   4951     return output

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   4947 
   4948     if copy:
-> 4949         output = [x.copy() for x in output]
   4950 
   4951     return output

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py in wrapped_method(self, *args, **params)
   2576     """
   2577     def wrapped_method(self, *args, **params):
-> 2578         result = getattr(self._data, funcname)(*args, **params)
   2579         result = result.view(type(self))
   2580         result._update_from(self)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 227. TiB for an array with shape (7898880, 7898880) and data type float32

x,y = mp(lon, lat)
Out:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6908/3885003198.py in <module>
----> 1 x,y = mp(lon, lat)

NameError: name 'lon' is not defined

c_scheme = mp.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(tir1[0, :, :]), cmap = 'jet')

Out: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6908/254152092.py in <module>
----> 1 c_scheme = mp.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(tir1[0, :, :]), cmap = 'jet')

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: I edited your code to improve formatting and remove obvious duplicate lines. HDF5 is a container, with a user defined schema. As such, It's hard to give specific advice without more details about the data. You can help by sharing shape of TIR and VIS datasets: `tir1.shape` and `vis.shape` and for latitude/longitude: `lat.shape` and `lon.shape`. If `lat` has shape `(M,)` and `lon` has shape `(N,)`, I would expect `tir1` and `vis` to have shape `(M,N)` to match. If not, more investigation is required.

Comment: I have coded a bit further and edited the code I posted earlier and I think you will get relevant info below:(and thanks for replying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another code to obtain the same results:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fn = '3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5' #filename (the ".h5" file) 
hf = h5py.File(fn, 'r')
hf.keys()
data = hf.get('IMG_TIR1')
data = data[0,:,:]
data=np.where(data>1022, np.nan, data)

Lat= hf.get('Latitude')
Lat = Lat[:,:]
Lat=Lat*0.0099999998
Lat=np.where(Lat>312, np.nan, Lat)

Long= hf.get('Longitude')
Long = Long[:,:]
Long=Long*0.0099999998
Long=np.where(Long>312, np.nan, Long)

X=Long[427:1421,804:1902]
Y=Lat[427:1421,804:1902]
Z=data[427:1421,804:1902]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z)
plt.xlim(60, 100)
plt.ylim(0, 40)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar(label="Radiance", orientation="vertical")
plt.xlim(60, 100)
plt.ylim(0, 40)

#Threshold
Zn=np.where(Z>810, 1, 0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.pcolor(X, Y, Zn, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(label="Radiance", orientation="vertical")
plt.xlim(60, 100)
plt.ylim(0, 40)
```

Comment: @kcw78 I posted another code to obtain the same results. Could you please tell me how to draw boundaries around the clouds using OpenCV library?  (In matlab bwboundaries is used to do the tracing) but I'm not sure how to do it in python

Answer (score 4):

@Black Viking, answering your question was more complicated than I initially perceived. I started from your code in the comments. After some digging, I determined the data in each `'IMG_xxx'` dataset is a raw raster image (scan), and the values in the associated longitude and latitude datasets are the (lon,lat) locations for each pixel. They don't form a regular MxN grid, so can't be used with matplotlib's `contourf()` function. So, my previous answer is incorrect. (I will delete most of it to avoid confusing future readers.)

As I worked on this, I discovered plotting satellite raster images on a map with a different coordinate system is not a simple task (going from Geostationary to a Mercator projection). Things you have to do:

1. Define the origin coordinate reference system for the image.
2. When plotting an image in a Geostationary system, to display the axes you need to add `extent=`  to `plt.imshow()`.
3. When plotting an image in a different coordinate system, you must transform the image to the new system with `'transform='` and `plt.imshow()`.

I am going to post the code incrementally to show how to go from a simple raster plot in a Geostationary system to the same image in a Mercator projection focused on the India region. Please read to the end -- there is some additional info you might need if something doesn't work.

**Plot 0**: Starting point from your comments (modified slightly). This only plots the raw IMG_TIR1 image data only.

```
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fn = '3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5' #filename (the ".h5" file)
with h5py.File(fn) as f:  
    img_arr = f['IMG_TIR1'][0,:,:] 
    
fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10)) 
plt.title('plot raw IMG_TIR1 image data (only)')
im = plt.imshow(img_arr) 
plt.colorbar(im)
```

**Plot 0 (w/ coastlines, image trimmed)**: This is a small modification to add the coastlines to the raw IMG_TIR1 image data. This was my reference to verify Mercator projections were correctly oriented in the following images. Note how it uses `extent=img_extent_sat` so the axes are displayed correctly. This is tricky because Geostationary Coordinates are **not** (longitude, latitude). `ax.get_extent(projection=)` returns the map extents for that projection. I had to increase them slightly to get the image to "fit" the axes.

```
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fn = '3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5' #filename (the ".h5" file)
with h5py.File(fn) as f:  
    img_arr = f['IMG_TIR1'][0,:,:] 
    
map_proj = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=82.0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax.coastlines(color='white')

# Image extent in Geostationary coordinates:
img_extent_sat = ax.get_extent(crs=map_proj)    
img_extent_sat = [1.04*x for x in img_extent_sat]

im = plt.imshow(img_arr, extent=img_extent_sat) 
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.title('plot raw IMG_TIR1 data + Geostationary coastlines')
```

Here is the code to create plots in the Mercator projection. To avoid repetition, I posted code segments for each step. Use the first ('base") section and add sections for the plot you want.

**Base Code**: Gets image data and attributes along with satellite attributes from HDF5 file.  I defined `image = 'IMG_TIR1'` so you can easily modify to get other `IMG_name` data. The Radiance attributes are only required if you want to calculate radiance from the image data (count values). The last line creates a masked array that maskes the`_FillValue` data in the corners and simplifies image plotting.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
    
fn = '3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5' #filename (the ".h5" file)
with h5py.File(fn) as f:      
    # retrieve image data:
    image = 'IMG_TIR1'
    img_arr = f[image][0,:,:] 
    # get _FillValue for data masking
    img_arr_fill = f[image].attrs['_FillValue'][0]   

# retrieve extent of plot from file attributes:
    left_lon = f.attrs['left_longitude'][0]
    right_lon = f.attrs['right_longitude'][0]
    lower_lat = f.attrs['lower_latitude'][0]
    upper_lat = f.attrs['upper_latitude'][0]
    sat_long = f.attrs['Nominal_Central_Point_Coordinates(degrees)_Latitude_Longitude'][1]
    sat_hght = f.attrs['Observed_Altitude(km)'][0] * 1000.0 # (for meters)

# retrieve attributes to calculate radiance from count:    
    Sensor_Name = f.attrs['Sensor_Name'].decode('utf-8') 
    img_fill = f[image].attrs['_FillValue'][0]   
    img_inv  = f[image].attrs['invert'].decode('utf-8')
    img_lrquad = f[image].attrs['lab_radiance_quad'][0]
    img_lrscale = f[image].attrs['lab_radiance_scale_factor'][0]
    img_lroff = f[image].attrs['lab_radiance_add_offset'][0]
print('Done reading HDF5 file')  

## Use np.ma.masked_equal with integer values to  
## mask '_FillValue' data in corners:
img_arr_m = np.ma.masked_equal(img_arr, img_arr_fill, copy=True)
```

**Plot 1**: Projects masked image data to full Mercator projection. Notice how `ax1.imshow()` uses `transform=data_crs` where `data_crs` references a Geostationary projection of the image data. Note: If you plot `img_arr` instead of `img_arr_m`, you will see the yellow '_FillValue' "halo" around the image. Also, I added numbers to `ax#` and `im#` to simplify plotting the following 3 figures as subplots on 1 figure.

```
# Plot 1 uses Mercator projection
print('Start on Plot1')

map_proj = ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=sat_long,
                      min_latitude=lower_lat, max_latitude=upper_lat)
data_crs = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=sat_long,
                              satellite_height=sat_hght)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1 = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax1.coastlines()
#ax1.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.5)
ax1.gridlines(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75, draw_labels=True)

map_proj_text = f'{str(type(map_proj)).split(".")[-1][:-2]}'
data_crs_text = f'{str(type(data_crs)).split(".")[-1][:-2]}'
plt.title(f'Plot1: Projection: {map_proj_text}\n' + \
          f'Data Transform: {data_crs_text}\n' + \
          f'\nRaster Data: {image} (masked)')
print('plotting data for Plot1 image')
im1 = ax1.imshow(img_arr_m, origin='upper', transform=data_crs)
plt.colorbar(im1)

print('done with Plot1')
```

**Plot 2**: Projects masked image data to a trimmed Mercator projection. The map size is defined with the `map_extent_merc` parameter in `ax2.set_extent()`. Note that Mercator coordinates are not in degrees, so I created a function to transform the extent values (`transform_extent_pts()`). (For your data, it goes from `map_extent_deg` in PlateCarree to `map_extent_merc` in Mercator). Try different values of `map_extent_deg` to see how the map changes.

```
# Plot 2 on Mercator projection
print('Start on Plot2')

map_proj = ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=sat_long,
                      min_latitude=lower_lat, max_latitude=upper_lat)
data_crs = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=sat_long,
                              satellite_height=sat_hght)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax2 = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax2.coastlines()
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.5)
ax2.gridlines(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75, draw_labels=True)

# Focus map on Indian subcontinent:
deg_crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
map_extent_deg = (15., 150., -67., 67.) # lon/lat focused on image
#map_extent_deg = (60.0, 97.0, -10.0, 37.5) # India
map_extent_merc = transform_extent_pts(map_extent_deg, map_proj, deg_crs)

ax2.set_extent(map_extent_merc, map_proj)

map_proj_text = f'{str(type(map_proj)).split(".")[-1][:-2]}'
data_crs_text = f'{str(type(data_crs)).split(".")[-1][:-2]}'
plt.title(f'Plot2: Projection: {map_proj_text}\n' + \
          f'Data Transform: {data_crs_text}\n' + \
          f"\nRaster Data: {image} (masked) ")
print('plotting data for Plot2 image')
im2 = plt.imshow(img_arr_m, origin='upper', transform=data_crs)
plt.colorbar(im2)

print('done with Plot2')
```

**Transform function used in Plot 2**:

```
def transform_extent_pts(extent_pts, map_proj, pt_crs):
    
    xul, yul = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[0],
        y = extent_pts[3],
        src_crs = pt_crs)
    
    xlr, ylr = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[1],
        y = extent_pts[2],
        src_crs = pt_crs)

    return [xul, xlr, ylr, yul]
```

**Plot 3**: Calculates and displays radiance values. Previous plots display the raw image data (which is "count"). The paper you provided has the equation to convert "count" to radiance. I wrote a function to do that (`calc_radiance()`). This only requires a few minor changes from above as explained below.

First, add the radiance function.

```
def transform_extent_pts(extent_pts, map_proj, pt_crs):
    
    xul, yul = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[0],
        y = extent_pts[3],
        src_crs = pt_crs)
    
    xlr, ylr = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[1],
        y = extent_pts[2],
        src_crs = pt_crs)

    return [xul, xlr, ylr, yul]
```

Add the following lines BEFORE: `print('Start on Plot2')` to calculate the radiance values. This data is used for Plot 3:

```
# Plot 3: Plot radiance on Mercator projection
print('Calculate radiance for Plot3')
radiance = calc_radiance(img_arr_m, img_lrquad, img_lrscale, img_lroff,
                         invert=img_inv, Sensor_Name=Sensor_Name)
```

Next, modify axis references from `ax2` to `ax3`.
Finally, modify the following 3 lines at the end:

```
plt.title(f'Plot3: Projection: {map_proj_text}\n' + \
          f'Data Transform: {map_proj_text}\n' + \
          f'\nRadiance from: {image} (masked)')
print('plot image for Plot3')
im3 = ax3.imshow(radiance, origin='upper', transform=data_crs)
plt.colorbar(im3)
print('done with Plot3')
```

**Plot 4**: Adjust image data to plot cloud thresholds. This is similar to Plot 3. You can use the `np.where()` function to create a new image array using thresholds (less than, greater than, or both). Also, I added `vmin=, vmax=` parameters to match the colorbar range to your plot. Only a few minor changes are required. For brevity, only changes are explained below.

```
# Plot 4: Plot cloud thresholds on Mercator projection
print('Calculate cloud mask for Plot4')
# Left Plot: set values <=700 to 0
cloud1 = np.where(img_arr_m <= 700, 0, img_arr_m)
# Right Plot: set values <=700 to 0, >700 to 1
cloud2 = np.where(img_arr_m <= 700, 0, 1)
.....
.....
print('plot image for Plot4')
# to create plot on left:
im4 = ax4.imshow(cloud1, vmin=0, vmax=1000, origin='upper', transform=data_crs)
# to create plot on right:
im4 = ax4.imshow(cloud2, vmin=0, vmax=1, origin='upper', transform=data_crs)
plt.colorbar(im4)
```

**Background and Reference info:**
Note: I had problems transforming GeoStationary images with earlier versions. I had to use cartopy v0.20.2 with Proj 8.2.1 to get these images. If you have problems, run this example to test: [Reprojecting images from a Geostationary projection](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/scalar_data/geostationary.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scalar-data-geostationary-py)

Also, here are links to 2 blog posts that are helpful (both include Python code):

1. [Blog tutorial](https://geonetcast.wordpress.com/2019/07/29/python-satellite-imagery-quickstart/)  with a detailed guide to plotting whole earth imagery in cartopy
2. [Another blog tutorial](https://www.net-analysis.com/blog/cartopyimages.html) that shows how to plot a satellite image from a WMS with  cartopy.

Finally, StackOverflow has some good Q&A on this topic. Search using `tag: [cartopy] 'satellite'` to find some good articles.

Comment: Thankyou @kcw78 , I was able to get the output from the code that you provided, I just had to do some minor changes in the extent.  i.e from `map_extent_deg = (15., 150., -67., 67.) # lon/lat focused on image`  to `map_extent_deg = (65., 100., 0., 40.) # lon/lat focused on image`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. For India, I guessed `#map_extent_deg = (60.0, 97.0, -10.0, 37.5) # India` in the commented statement below.  - which was pretty close. :-) Maybe you didn't notice it? If this answer solves your problem, please indicate for those that read in the future.

Comment: Yeah sure, and thanks again

Comment: I wanted to ask you one more thing, Is there a way to show threshold of clouds in the image. In other word is there a way to represent IMG_TIR1 or others  in such a way that we can see colors in the spaces where cloud is present. And I'm sharing an image that shows what I mean https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_4zAQ7eWdoovlV8WbUFRlnuRnKuM8na/view?usp=sharing (But its done in MATLAB & not by me).

Comment: You can create a plot with any image data is in the file. I can't find values that match the images in your link. Do you know which dataset was used to create the MATLAB image? And how did they calculate the values on the right from the ones on the left?

Comment: Its the same dataset (IMG_TIR1) and the created by using commands shown here in the image :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Da3cm5PUNYNhfUnlsj32njsgXHd-WFbZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If I understand, the 1st plot shows TIR1 values. The 2nd plot has values=0 where TIR1<700 and values=1 where TIR1>=700. Is that correct? If so, that can be done by creating a new array from `img_arr_m` and plotting it (instead of `img_arr_m`). Also are you plotting longitude 60->100 and latitude 0->60?

Comment: I added **Plot 4** to my answer showing how to get a new image array using cloud thresholds. I think this mimics the MATLAB code in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't find the data, I used **HDFView** from The HDF Group to generate an image from the data. This is for `IMG_TIR1`.
At this point, I need more info about the file schema to "find" this data. Does the MOSDAC website have anything that describes the file schema, or maybe some code that shows how to read the data?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who may read these in the future: The code provided by @kcw78 is correct and you only have to do some minor changes in the extent of the image data. For me I changed it from `map_extent_deg = (15., 150., -67., 67.)` to `map_extent_deg = (65., 100., 0., 40.)` for Indian region. Like so you may have to change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may read these in the future: The code provided by @kcw78 is correct and you only have to do some minor changes in the extent of the image data. For me I changed it from `map_extent_deg = (15., 150., -67., 67.)` to `map_extent_deg = (65., 100., 0., 40.)`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. The check (under the arrows) is used to "accept" the answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. It is an indication to others that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 2022-03-08**: Pseudo-code in my original post used `plt.contourf()` to plot the data. That does not work with raster image data saved in `'IMG_TIR1'` dataset. Instead, `plt.imshow()` must be used. See detailed answer posted on 2022-03-07 for the complete procedure.

All `'IMG_name'` datasets are raster image data. I modified the code to show a simple example that reads the HDF5 file with h5py, then plots the image data with matplotlib and cartopy on a Geostationary (original satellite) projection. I picked cartopy based on this comment on the Basemap site: "Deprecation Notice: Basemap is deprecated in favor of the Cartopy project." I'm sure it can be modified to use Basemap to plot and NetCDF to read the HDF5 file.

**Updated code below:**

```
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# First get data from HDF5 file with h5py:
fn = '3DIMG_30MAR2018_0000_L1B_STD.h5' #filename (the ".h5" file)
with h5py.File(fn) as data: 
    tir1 = data['IMG_TIR1'][:].reshape(lats.shape)
# retrieve extent of plot from file attributes:
    left_lon = data.attrs['left_longitude'][0]
    right_lon = data.attrs['right_longitude'][0]
    lower_lat = data.attrs['lower_latitude'][0]
    upper_lat = data.attrs['upper_latitude'][0]  
    sat_long = data.attrs['Nominal_Central_Point_Coordinates(degrees)_Latitude_Longitude'][1]

# Define extent of plot (in degrees) as:
# extent=[longitude_top_left,longitude_top_right,
#         latitude_bottom_left,latitude_top_left]
# coordinates must be transformed to map coordinate system before using
img_extent_deg = (left_lon, right_lon, lower_lat, upper_lat)

# Create Geostationary plot with cartopy and matplotlib    
map_proj = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=sat_long)
ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax.coastlines(color='white')
map_extend_geos = ax.get_extent(crs=map_proj)
plt.imshow(tir1, extent=map_extend_geos)
plt.colorbar(im1)
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10v3B8yUAx-KyGUmYSwS0s2WLKnl-l9Fm/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                           
     I'm sharing the drive link to the file

Comment: I fixed the error to read `lats, lons, and tir` **BUT** that does not help very much. All 3 datasets contain default `_FillValue`. They have attributes with object references pointing to other datasets. And those datasets also have object references. I tried to track them down, but can't find the actual data. I looked at `IMG_TIR_TEMP` and `IMG_TIR_RADIANCE`, but they don't have enough data for all `lons,lats` coordinates.

Comment: The above image showing the IMG_TIR1 is already obtained  by using the below code:  ```vis = f['IMG_MIR'][0,:,:]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
im1 = plt.imshow(vis)
plt.colorbar(im1)```                                                                                                               
 But the problem is that I have to show the output as Indian region only by using the lat and lon. And yes there is a PDF file with me that has all the necessary data and information about data structure==   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MXB_acmMq98JGil2KYH8JmEIqnpTwVAT/view?usp=sharing