# Reprojection of INSAT geostationary .h5 file to EPSG:4326

Tags: python, mapping, python-xarray, map-projections, rasterio

I am trying to reproject my .h5 of INSAT LST to get an transformed mercator lat lon coordinates EPSG:4326.

I have used rio.reproject but not working, the reprojected lat lon are all weird , so the Central_Point_Coordinates Latitude for INSAT image is 82 deg so after reprojection, it seems to start from there. rio.reproject method was successful in reprojection of MODIS Sin grid to LAT Lon grid but for INSAT. I am stuck.
Initially when I used this method for the file, it gave error crs not found so for the INSAT file, I assigned the crs.

I also came across this [Reading and plotting HDF5(.h5) file and showing map for a specific latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239113/reading-and-plotting-hdf5-h5-file-and-showing-map-for-a-specific-latitude-and) & [How to plot the map correctly over the SST data in cartopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756041/how-to-plot-the-map-correctly-over-the-sst-data-in-cartopy) article and for plotting it seems to work but I want the dataset/array to be transformed and be in Lat/Lon in deg(EPSG:4326) Grid.

```
import os
import warnings
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import glob
import rioxarray as rxr
from shapely.geometry import mapping, box
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

a2=xr.open_dataset('/home/data/lab_d/../ncf/3DIMG_19APR2015_1100_L2B_LST.h5')
a2 = a2.drop('Latitude', dim=None)
a2 = a2.drop('Longitude', dim=None)
a2 = a2.rename({'GeoX':'x'})
a2 = a2.rename({'GeoY':'y'})
a2=a2.rio.write_crs('+proj=geos +h=35785831.0 +lon_0=82')


ins_lonlat = a2.rio.reproject(dst_crs="EPSG:4326",shape=(2805,2816))
ins_lonlat
```

```
Attributes :

conventions :
    CF-1.6
title :
    3DIMG_19APR2015_1100_L2B
institute :
    BES,SAC/ISRO,Ahmedabad,INDIA.
source :
    IMAGER (IMG)
Unique_Id :
    3DIMG_19APR2015_1100
Satellite_Name :
    INSAT-3D
Sensor_Id :
    IMG
Sensor_Name :
    IMAGER
HDF_Product_File_Name :
    3DIMG_19APR2015_1100_L2B_LST.h5
Output_Format :
    hdf5-1.8.8
Station_Id :
    BES
Ground_Station :
    BES,SAC/ISRO,Ahmedabad,INDIA.
Product_Type :
    GEOPHY
Processing_Level :
    L2B
Imaging_Mode :
    FULL FRAME
Acquisition_Date :
    19APR2015
Acquisition_Time_in_GMT :
    1100
Acquisition_Start_Time :
    19-APR-2015T11:00:01
Acquisition_End_Time :
    19-APR-2015T11:26:52
Product_Creation_Time :
    2015-04-19T16:55:26
Radiometric_Calibration_Type :
    LAB CALIBRATED
Nominal_Altitude(km) :
    36000.0
Observed_Altitude(km) :
    35786.49337
Nominal_Central_Point_Coordinates(degrees)_Latitude_Longitude :
    [ 0. 82.]
Attitude_Source :
    STAR
Sun_Azimuth(Degrees) :
    281.851349
Sat_Azimuth(Degrees) :
    292.674438
Sat_Elevation(Degrees) :
    89.86808
Sun_Elevation(Degrees) :
    19.292431
FastScan_Linearity_Enabled :
    no
SlowScan_Linearity_Enabled :
    no
Software_Version :
    1.0
left_longitude :
    0.8432964
right_longitude :
    163.15671
upper_latitude :
    81.04153
lower_latitude :
    -81.04153
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y7Mb2BfwuL443ypchMCXbExsWS40BNS6/view?usp=share_link  this is the file so it will be really appreciated for the help.

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the issue, but EPSG:4326 is WGS84 (lat/lons on a geoid) and is NOT Mercator. World Mercator is [3395](https://epsg.io/3395) and web Mercator is [3857](https://epsg.io/3857)

Comment: That said, the units of Mercator are meters, so if you’re looking for lat/lons in degrees you’re probably looking for wgs84/epsg4326 after all?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet Hi @MichaelDelgado, you are correct I want Lat/ Lon in degrees, so it will be EPSG:4326 is WGS84 (lat/lons on a geoid). Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the post. But as I mentioned after re projecting , the xaxis seems to be starting from 80 deg and y is all weird.

Comment: Please can you share the web link to where you download the data? I.e the website you are downloading the raw data from (not your Google drive)

Comment: https://mosdac.gov.in/doi-landing-page?t=doi&id=149  , https://www.mosdac.gov.in/catalog/satellite.php?mission=INSAT-3D in this 3DIMG_L2B_LST product